# How to log data of a Java(FX) application?

Tags: java, mysql, database, logging

What is the best way to log data of a Java (also using JavaFX) application for later reviewing? A few other people and I are working on a project, with a client/server model, and we want to log all data in the server for reviewing it later and possibly use it for calculations (later).

So a simple text file won't do, because the data needs to be reviewed in a clear way and can be used for later calculations. You can say that we want a small database that integrates well with Java, but using one like MySQL will require all the server setup and it seems to cumbersome in this situation.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do. May be the problem is that you don't want a tecnical log, but you want to collect business data. Please tell us how your application get's the data. Is there a central data base?

Comment: I already figured it out. What I meant is actually saving the data with SQL queries which makes it possible to retrieve this data if calculations want to be made, or reviewing needs to be done. We chose for HSQLDB. What do you think? Is there also a way to read the .data file of the HSQLDB if the application is shutdown?

Answer (score 1):

Probably the best option right now is to use [slf4j](http://www.slf4j.org/) as the API, and [logback](http://logback.qos.ch/) as the implementation.

That'll allow you to change the physical repository of your log data, without changing your code.

I also suggest you to read this article:

http://glauche.de/2009/09/09/java-util-logging-vs-slf4j/

Comment: Hi, and how is the reviewing done later? The users of this application hava no knowledge in computer science. They want to be able to review the data of their application (which we are developing) in a simple way. We on the other hand want to implement functionality for using this data if for example a new client subscribes to the server

Comment: logback allows you to write your log data into a database. It has a predefined "appender" for it, but you can implement your own in case you consider it necessary. Take a look at this: http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html

Comment: You can use different logging levels (debug, info, warn etc) and some topic related tags in your log to ease a later analysis. I aggree that slf4j really seems to be a  great logging library with a good performance. I'm using it at work for frequent logging.

Comment: Wouldn't something like HSQLDB be much better for what we are trying to do? We want to save data only for later reviewing and calculations. What do you think?

Comment: With slf4j/logback ,you can use a database for storing your log data. What this API/framework provide you is a layer of abstraction between your code and the way you write your logs. In the middle/long term, this decoupling will be very useful.

Answer (score 0):

The JDK commes with the [java.util.logging package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/logging/package-summary.html). This gives you all you need for logging.

Comment: Would it also work with the cases I described to Andres?